# How do i "nest" different th's inside a table header

Tags: html, nested, head

I'm trying to make a table head where two th's are nested into another th.

example |th1  |th2  |th3    |th6  |th7  |
        |     |     |th4 th5|     |     |
The panel is messing up the layout here but th4 and th5 are supposed to go under th3 while everyting (appears) to remain in one row.

Sorry for the maybe vague description...
In principle I'm only "allowed" to use html at this point...

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC1Hi.png)

Comment: show some sample code you tried. And be specific while explaining what you really looking for

Comment: apologies, i added some info and a picture of the type of table i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this kind of table.

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table-zebra tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.zui-table-zebra tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEF7EE;
}
.zui-table-horizontal tbody td {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="zui-table zui-table-zebra zui-table-horizontal">
  <col>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Teddy Bears</th>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this one puts the tableheads in two rows. I was looking for something like subcategories inside one of the th's in the first row (splitting one th, containing two th under it, all this in line with the main th's)

Comment: i included a link to an exapmle image of the table i need (very small)

Comment: i included a decent image this time ;)

Comment: add as a picture instead of image link.